# Get SPListItem from LINQ

Tags: development, splistitem, linq, spmetal

I have used SPMetal to create a data context. I can query my lists. The queries return an object of the type of list that they are in. Is it possible to convert this type into a normal SPListItem object?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can call it directly if im correct:

```
List<SPListItem> items = (from l in list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>() where l["KPI Status"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(l["KPI Status"]) == 1 select l).ToList<SPListItem>();
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: This answer uses Linq, but not SPMetal

Comment: sorry the answer was based on his title, Get SPListItem from LINQ :)